# SQL distinct b,a couple when a,b couple are already in the result

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I am using the mondial database that can be queried at http://www.semwebtech.org/sqlfrontend/

I am trying to get all the countries that share a mountain, I tried the following query

```
select distinct country1.name, country2.name
from (select distinct geo1.country as c1, geo2.country as c2
      from geo_mountain geo1 join
           geo_mountain geo2
           on geo1.mountain = geo2.mountain and
              not(geo1.country = geo2.country)
     ) mountain,
     country country1, country country2
where country1.code = mountain.c1 and country2.code = mountain.c2
```

---

The problem is that I get each couple of values 2 times, one time **countryA, countryB** and another time **countryB, countryA** how can I get rid of the second couple of values as they are already in the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper `join` syntax:

```
select c1.name, c2.name
from (select distinct geo1.country as c1, geo2.country as c2
      from geo_mountain geo1 join
           geo_mountain geo2
           on geo1.mountain = geo2.mountain and
              geo1.country < geo2.country
     ) mountain join
     country c1
     on mountain.c1 = c1.code join
     country c2
     on mountain.c2 = c2.code;
```

The `<` fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about mountains that aren't shared by 2 but 3 countries (such as Mousa Ali or Zapaleri)? I mean, do you really need two columns, or ...?

Consider such a query:

```
select m.mountain,
  listagg (c.name, ', ') within group (order by c.name) countries
from geo_mountain m, country c
where m.mountain in (select mountain
                     from geo_mountain
                     group by mountain
                     having count(distinct country) > 1
                    )
  and c.code = m.country
group by m.mountain
order by m.mountain;
```